# Schedule functions run and allow only one function to run at a time

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to write a Python script to do the following. Let's say I have function A and function B, each taking a certain time to execute. For example:

```
def A(arg):
    time.sleep(4)

def B(arg):
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have a list of arguments I want the functions to go through, for example:

```
args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to first run `A(1)`. Once `A(1)` is completed, I want to have some kind of timer to start running, so that after 10 seconds `B(1)` will be executed. To make things more efficient, I want to run `A(2)` immediately after `A(1)` is completed, during the 10 seconds delay. 10 seconds after `A(2)` is completed, I want to run `B(2)`. And so on and so forth for the other arguments.
One important constraint is that there can only be one function execution at a time, no function execution overlap is allowed. If, for example, the 10 seconds delay is over for an execution of function B to take place, but another function is running, the execution of function B will have to wait until the other function is over.

I tried to do it by myself and I think I am almost there, the only problem is that I can't get only one function to run at a time:

```
import threading
import time

def A(arg):
    print(f"A({arg}) started at {time.time()}")
    time.sleep(4)
    print(f"A({arg}) finished at {time.time()}")

def B(arg):
    print(f"B({arg}) started at {time.time()}")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"B({arg}) finished at {time.time()}")

def run_a_then_b(arg):
    A(arg)
    timer = threading.Timer(10, B, args=(arg,))
    timer.start()

args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for arg in args:
    run_a_then_b(arg)  # Execute function A followed by scheduling function B
```

And this is what I see in the console:

```
A(1) started at 1694782594.3680944
A(1) finished at 1694782598.3811712
A(2) started at 1694782598.3811712
A(2) finished at 1694782602.3866756
A(3) started at 1694782602.3866756
A(3) finished at 1694782606.3930645
A(4) started at 1694782606.3930645
B(1) started at 1694782608.388662
B(1) finished at 1694782609.4038901
A(4) finished at 1694782610.4036424
A(5) started at 1694782610.4036424
B(2) started at 1694782612.4008462
B(2) finished at 1694782613.4127486
A(5) finished at 1694782614.4137204
B(3) started at 1694782616.4016998
B(3) finished at 1694782617.4075282
B(4) started at 1694782620.4106658
B(4) finished at 1694782621.4245982
B(5) started at 1694782624.4142904
B(5) finished at 1694782625.4247322
```

As you see, B(1) starts running while A(4) is running, but I want B(1) to wait until A(4) is done.
Could you please help me fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the `threading.Lock` and it helped me solve the issue. This is how I implemented it:

```
import threading
import time

lock = threading.Lock()

def A(arg):
    lock.acquire()
    print(f"A({arg}) started at {time.time()}")
    time.sleep(4)
    print(f"A({arg}) finished at {time.time()}")
    lock.release()

def B(arg):
    lock.acquire()
    print(f"B({arg}) started at {time.time()}")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"B({arg}) finished at {time.time()}")
    lock.release()
    
def run_a_then_b(arg):
    A(arg)
    timer = threading.Timer(10, B, args=(arg,))
    timer.start()
    
args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for arg in args:
    run_a_then_b(arg)  # Execute function A followed by scheduling function B
```

By having each function holding the lock every time it is executed, only one function at a time can be executed.